# Why apache2 mod_cache_disk cant store files in ramdisk?

Tags: apache2, cache, ramdisk

I use Apache2 mod_cache_disk with symlink to my ramdisk: **/tmp/ramdisk/mod_cache_disk**
but I cant get it to work :( It only works when path leads to real directory. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Just mount another ramdisk where you need it.

Comment: "Can't get it to work" is not a very clear description. I'm afraid I am unable to deduce anything from that. Would you mind sharing what you tried and in which ways the results diverged from what you expected?